The Data Table (unofficialsf screen component) record name link is not targeting to Sandbox environment
The field Teachable Moment Name is the standard record name. And the url is not taking me to the correct environment.
When I am configuring the columns in the Flow builder the url seems correct:

However when I run the flow in debug mode, I get linked to Production instead of Sandbox. Or even with the active flow from anywhere in the org.

Am I doing something wrong?

You will have to check the Unofficial SF support resources
